# C# .NET MAUI - page layout doesn't resize properly when the Editor keyboard pops up .NET 7. Works in 6

Tags: c#, editor, maui

Anyone know what's going on here?  This works in .NET 6 but not 7

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ( )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );

        BoxView box = new BoxView { Color = Colors.LightBlue } ;

        VerticalStackLayout layout = new VerticalStackLayout ( ) ;
        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView { Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical , Content = layout } ;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ )
        {
            layout.Add ( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Wheat , HeightRequest = 75 } );
            layout.Add ( new BoxView { Color = Colors.LightCyan , HeightRequest = 75 } );
        }

        Editor editor = new Editor { BackgroundColor = Colors.Green } ;

        Grid grid = new Grid ( ) ;

        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = 100 } );
        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength ( 1 , GridUnitType.Star ) } );
        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = 100 } );

        grid.Add ( box , 0 , 0 );
        grid.Add ( scroll , 0 , 1 );
        grid.Add ( editor , 0 , 2 );

        MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = grid };
    }
}
```

Using .NET 7 I'm trying to programmatically add an Editor the MainPage and have the layout adjust properly when the keyboard pops up.  At the moment, the entire page above the keyboard slides up the same height as the keyboard when that page should condense in the middle grid .STAR element.  Works in .NET 6

Comment: IMHO if the behaviour changed between .net 6 and .net 7, I would say it is a bug and therefor I would have posted it here instead: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Answer (score 4):

You may set the **WindowSoftInputModeAdjust** attached property to **Resize**. Try the following code:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
         android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize"
         ...>
    <Application.Resources>
    ....
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Soft keyboard input mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: I had the exact same problem, worked in Net6 (when the soft keyboard opened, the Grid above was resized to fit the remaining screen area, the grid remained visible), but not in Net7 (the grid shifted up, top content becoming invisible).
Liqun Shen-MSFT's answer solved the problem in my case.